# Прокрутка колеса мыши

Tags: jquery, javascript

Как ограничить прокрутку колесика мыши только 1-им событием, в моем случае это `alert(way)`?

Дело в том что когда прокручивается колесо мыши, то происходит сразу несколько alert'ов (событий), можете сами убедиться на этом примере:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){

    var tempScrollTop,currentScrollTop = 0;

    var way = "default"; // направление

        $(window).scroll(function()
        {

            currentScrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();

            if (tempScrollTop < currentScrollTop)
            { 
                way= "down"; // крутнули вниз колесо
            } 
            else if (tempScrollTop > currentScrollTop)
            {
                way= "up"; // крутнули вверх колесо
            }

            tempScrollTop = currentScrollTop;

            alert(way);

        });

    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
<style>
body { height: 3000px; }
</style>
</body>
</html>
```

Возможно ли как это отрегулировать, чтобы на 1-ну прокрутку срабатывало только 1-но событие, т.е. 1 `alert`?

по возможности, если кто ни въехал или скрип работает правильно, попробуйте открыть в IE 8, поймете в чем дело.

нда... что-то не получилось у меня фишка, расскажу более подробно о глобальной задаче:
имеется слайдер, который работает по скроллу, скроллит к нужному якорю, все это относится к ИЕ, в частности к 8-й его версии, так как на других я ни тестил, сейчас это выглядит так:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="underscore-min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){

var tempScrollTop,currentScrollTop = 0;

var way = "default";

// array of the anchors
var jak = new Array("jak1","jak2","jak3","jak4");
i = 0;

// scroll to id
function goToByScroll(id)
{  
$('html,body').animate({scrollTop: $("#"+id).offset().top},"fast"); 
}

$(window).scroll(function()
{

currentScrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();

if (tempScrollTop < currentScrollTop)
{ 
way= "down";
i++;
} 
else if (tempScrollTop > currentScrollTop)
{
way= "up";
i--;
}

tempScrollTop = currentScrollTop;

if (i<0) { ++i; }
if (i>=4){ --i; }

// so, we go the current anchor
goToByScroll(jak[i]);

});

});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<style>
html,body { width: 100%; height: 100%;}
div { margin: 0 auto; border: 1px solid; width: 500px; height: 100%; text-align: center; }
</style>
<div id="jak1">1</div>
<div id="jak2">2</div>
<div id="jak3">3</div>
<div id="jak4">4</div>
</body>
</html>
```

увы, это нерабочий вариант, хотя идеология правильная, обычную анимацию без полосы прокрутки я не могу использовать, это обусловлено тем что в телефонах тогда не будет работать, идиотизм может быть, но других я не вижу вариантов.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не уверен , что правильно понял, но [сделал такой варинт](http://jsfiddle.net/Deonis/8y9qf/), где срабатывать функция должна один раз при изменении направления прокрутки. (С алертом на фиддле бяда, посему результат вывел в див)

```
var tempScrollTop,currentScrollTop = 0;
var check_way = true;

var way = "default"; // направление
function showWay(str){
    $('div').text(str).fadeIn(300,function(){
        $('div').fadeOut(500);
    });

}
$(window).scroll(function(){
    currentScrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();
    if (tempScrollTop < currentScrollTop){
        way= "down"; // крутнули вниз колесо
        if(check_way){
            check_way = false;
            showWay(way);
        }
    } else if (tempScrollTop > currentScrollTop){
        way= "up"; // крутнули вверх колесо
        if(!check_way){
            check_way = true;
            showWay(way);
        }
    }
    tempScrollTop = currentScrollTop;
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Ну здесь уже можно поразмыслить чисто логически. И можно догадаться сделать хук,
который будет работать по простому принципу:

При каждом срабатывании скроллинга надо инкрементировать некий счетчик на единицу. Также в каждом срабатывании вашей функции проверяйте, не равно ли значение счетчика единице. Если равно, то завершаем работу функции. Но счетчик также надо будет обнулять! Делайте это в таймере с интервалом, к примеру, 0.5-0.7 секунд.